# Save variable value in session like cart with single form

Tags: php

I have a simple form in sidebar on 5 pages where i have two fields name and price. I want to save its value in session when user will submit the form. when i store its value in session after submit a form then it replace name every time. But i want to store name value like array. If user submit form with name user1 and then submit again with username user2 then i want to show these 2 names in session variable and want to show increment of form submit. Like cart functionality. Is there any way to store these value with a single form. Please help me.

```
 <form id="myform" action="post.php" method="POST">
<div class="row">
    <label for="name">Your name:</label><br />
    <input id="name" class="input" name="name" type="text" value=""  size="30" /><br />
</div>
<div class="row">
    <label for="price">Price:</label><br />
    <input id="price" class="input" name="price" type="text" value="" size="30" /><br />
</div>

<input id="submit_button" type="submit" value="submit" />
 </form>     

post.php
session_start();

$_SESSION['cart_items'] = array(); 
$_SESSION['cart_items'] = $_POST['name'];

foreach($_SESSION["cart_items"] as $cart_item)
{
    echo $cart_item;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add values to session by

```
session_start();
foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm) //loop through session array
        {
            if($cart_item["code"] == $product_code){ //the item exist in array

            $product[] = array('name'=>$cart_item["name"], 'code'=>$cart_item["code"], 'qty'=>$product_qty, 'price'=>$cart_item["price"]);
            $found = true;
        }else{
            //item doesn't exist in the list, just retrieve old info and prepare array for session var
            $product[] = array('name'=>$cart_item["name"], 'price'=>$cart_item["price"]);
        }
    }
```

Add the result by

```
foreach ($_SESSION["cart"] as $cart_item)
{
echo $cart_item["price"];
$subtotal = ($cart_item["price"]*$cart_item["qty"]);
$total = ($total + $subtotal);
}
echo $total;
```

Comment: But when i print $_SESSION['cart'] it shows only single value in this cart.

Comment: use your echo variable inside the **`foreach`** function then only all array value in session will be displayed...

Comment: Refer this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29859822/display-item-list-in-shopping-cart-using-php/30731297#30731297

Comment: It is showing Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Please help if there is any other solution.